# Matrix convolution for generating a Pascal Triangle row

Tags: matrices, convolution

Recently I came across an answer on Stackoverflow that uses matrix convolution (or vector convolution in this case). The answer says:

> First we chose the second row (1,1) to be a kernel and then in order to get the next row we only need to convolve curent row with the kernel.
>
> So convolution of the kernel with second row gives third row `[1 1]*[1 1] = [1 2 1]`, convolution with the third row gives fourth `[1 2 1]*[1 1] = [1 3 3 1]` and so on

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33810563)

I was interested in this and [read a bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution) and [some more](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs1114/2013sp/sections/S06_convolution.pdf), but it doesn't make sense to me yet. What exactly happens during a convolution of let's say two vectors? Why does `[1 2 1]*[1 1] = [1 3 3 1]`?

Moreover, the paper from Cornell I referenced gives this definition:

> Let’s call our input vector f and our kernel g, and say that f has length n, and g has length m. The convolution f ∗ g of f and g is defined as:
>   $$(f ∗ g)(i) = \sum_{j=1}^m g(j) · f(i − j + m/2)$$

But what is `i` in this case?

Comment: You can interpret the sequences as polynomial coefficients. Then the convolution sequence is the coefficient sequence of the product polynomial. Thus what you describe is just the binomial theorem, $(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i$.

Comment: @LutzL that sounds interesting but I don't exactly follow, could you expand maybe with an example or so?

Comment: Did you study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution or similar? Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of convolution like a shifting dot product. For $[1 \ 1]\star[1 \ 1]$:

```
  1 1
    1 1
-------
  0 1 0  = 1

  1 1
  1 1
------
  1 1 = 2

  1 1
1 1 
------
0 1 0 = 1
```

So the result is $[1 \ 2 \ 1]$.

Edit:
The definition given is basically what I have above. $i$ is which element of the convolution you want to calculate, $j$ is the summation index going from 1 to $m$. The summation here is basically just the dot product of $g$ and a shifted $f$. Technically $f$ is reflected as well, but since all vectors in your problem are symmetric, it can be ignored.

Comment: So, in the first example, you do `1 * 0 = 0`, `1 * 1 = 1` and `0 * 1 = 0` to get `0 1 0`?

Comment: Is there en explanation with a matrix instead of a vector?